# MVC 4 Entity Framework multiple insert

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Whats best way for that on MVC 4 with Entity Framework.

**Example:**

We have a form like that. Date will be same for all records. But Pax and Price will be change. And i dont want post that so many times. I need an ADD button for Pax and Price. And Date and Region will be same.

Pax: 1

Price: 500$

Date: DateTime.Now

Region: Location

And im using MVC model and Entity Framework

Im asking **BEST** way. I can do that with my old knowledges. Jquery append and Split at Form Behind my think. Thats true way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use knockout and dynamically add form elements using it. Then you can do a single post as an Ienumerable of your type. See the example here http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/

Knockout works great for scenarios like yours. You can encode the rules about same date etc in the add function of your viewmodel and make the form element non editable etc

Comment: If this answer has helped you then you can also upvote it as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public void PostArticle(List<Article> articles)
{
    foreach(var article in articles)
    {
        Context.AddObject(article);
    }
    Context.SaveAllChanges();
}


public ActionResult ShowArticles()
{
    //Returns list of articles (use a model for this)
    return View(Context.GetArticles());
}
```

You can also use a formcollection but then you would need to strip the dictionary by urself.